# Why the message is keeping outputting when l use cx_freeze to pack a program with xgboost and sklearn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

**test.py**:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.externals import joblib
#import pandas as pd
print ('i will be crazy!!!')
```

run `python3 test.py` and the result is:

```
/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py:15: DeprecationWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib. If this warning is raised when loading pickled models, you may need to re-serialize those models with scikit-learn 0.21+.
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
i will be crazy!!!
```

when l use cx_freeze to pack,run `python3 setup.py build`:

```
/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py:15: DeprecationWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib. If this warning is raised when loading pickled models, you may need to re-serialize those models with scikit-learn 0.21+.
                      warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
i will be crazy!!!
/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py:15: DeprecationWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib. If this warning is raised when loading pickled models, you may need to re-serialize those models with scikit-learn 0.21+.
                      warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
i will be crazy!!!
...
```

it keeps outputting the message aboved.
why? only those two packages have the problem.

**Version Info:**

- Python 3.7.0
- Cx_freeze 6.0b1

Comment: why don't you do what you have in this warning ? `pip install joblib` and `import joblib`

Comment: This is the right answer. You should not import `joblib` from `sklearn.externals`. The reason is that `joblib` is an individual package which will not be vendored in scikit-learn.

Comment: the solution is here:https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4067

Comment: use joblib 0.11 and problem sloved

Comment: Thanks I just imported the library instead of using it under scikit-learn